# FormObject line breaks. A bug?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, user-interface

There seems to be an issue with FormObject and line breaks:
A simple example to illustrate:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{
               FormObject[
                  {Style["Title", 26, RGBColor[{0.778, 0.423, 0.161}]],
                   Delimiter, 
                   Style["Subtitle", Bold],
                   Style["Description", Bold],
                   {"item", "item description"} -> RepeatingElement["Number"]}]}, 
             Identity], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

See the result here: Subtitle and Description on a single line

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/afdc6c20-2d0c-4aa9-ae2d-cbf6b3d7f501

Comment: It is better for the format of this site if you can take your problem and separate it from your workaround. Then, ask your problem in the form of a question, and post your workaround as a self-answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{
               FormObject[
                  {Style["Title", 26, RGBColor[{0.778, 0.423, 0.161}]],
                   Delimiter, 
                   Row[{Style["Subtitle", Bold],"<br>"}],
                   Style["Description", Bold],
                   {"item", "item description"} -> RepeatingElement["Number"]}]}, 
             Identity], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

That's available here:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7ab76933-ee8b-4446-af7f-7b2ee102ddfd

Manually inserting the <br> puts Subtitle and Description on separate lines